# EPI 5.10 Space Complexity Clairification

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm working on writing a function which takes a permutation (e.g `[2,0,1,3]` and an array to apply the permutation to (e.g `['a','b','c','d']`). With the above two inputs, the output would be `['b','c','a','d']`

The below solution comes straight from the book and claims to be O(1) space.

```
def apply_permutation(perm, A):
    for i in range(len(A)):
        next = i 
        while perm[next] >= 0:
            A[i], A[perm[next]] = A[perm[next]], A[i]
            temp = perm[next]
            perm[next] -= len(perm)
            next = temp 
    perm[:] = [a + len(perm) for a in perm]
    return A
```

However, isn't the line:

```
perm[:] = [a + len(perm) for a in perm]
```

creating a brand new array via a list comprehension and then assigning it to `perm`? In which case that's actually O(N) space?

Also, what's the value add in assigning the newly created list to `perm[:]` instead of `perm = ...`?

Comment: `perm[:] = ...` doesn't create a new list, but rather mutates the old one. (More memory efficient) From a point of memory efficiency you should also change the list comprehension to a generator comprehension.

Comment: Also you example output is wrong or am I missing something? It should be `['c', 'a', 'b', 'd']`

Comment: @MegaIng because `c` maps to index `1` in the permutation array, in the output of the function it should be placed at index 1. if that isn't clear from the question, happy to edit. Also, I know that you can assign to perm[:] and not use extra space - I'm talking specifically about creating a list via list comprehension to then write over perm with. Doesn't that create a brand new list in memory, using O(N)?

Comment: @MegaIng if one were to use a generator function to write over perm, e.g `perm[:] = generator_exp()`, then that would be O(1) space correct? But in this case, using a list comprehension is O(N)?

Comment: @MegaIng While `perm[:] =` doesn’t create a new list, the comprehension _does_ create a new list. So the OP is right—the old list and the new one are alive simultaneously for the duration of the `__setitem__` call, meaning there is linear temporary space.

Comment: PS, what is “the book” here?

Comment: @abarnert EPI = Elements of Programming Interview - which I thought was widely used but this isn't the first time I've encountered something that seems blatantly false.

Comment: @Sunny Looking at their website, they seem to really hammer home the fact that you need to make sure you get the latest edition of their books. Which implies they may know about some of these errors and have fixed them. But you’d think they’d have a prominent Errata section on their site, but all I can find is a bug report form… Anyway, I suppose if you know enough to catch many of the errors, it’s probably even more useful training for you than they intended. :)